# Where is the latch release on a Graco TurboBooster LX highback car seat?

Tags: car-seat

*I ran into this problem and solved it, so this Q&A is here just in case anyone else looked at the manual and was disappointed to discover it doesn't have any guidance on how to do the latch release*

On a Graco TurboBooster LX highback car seat (2079887 model number) I can't pull the latches out from the back of the seat, preventing installation. How does that work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, the rear latches / hooks have a red release button on the front of the seat. Pushing and holding the release button up while simultaneously pulling the latches from the rear of the seat allows them to be adjusted. No idea why that's not in the manual :/

As seen here: https://youtu.be/zfu6lME6gb0?t=196